# how can i apply style through javascript DOM in multiple <div> blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div
{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;

-webkit-transition: 1s ease 0s;

}
div:hover
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:100px;
-webkit-transform:matrix3d(0.359127, -0.469472, 0.806613, 0, 0.190951, 0.882948, 0.428884, 0, -0.913545, 0, 0.406737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

    
}

</style>
</head>
<body  bgcolor="black" onload="bbbl()">

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
<div id="f"></div>
<div id="g"></div>
<div id="h"></div>
<div id="i"></div>
<div id="j"></div>
<div id="k"></div>
<div id="l"></div>
<div id="m"></div>
<div id="n"></div>
<div id="o"></div>
<div id="p"></div>
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="r"></div>
<div id=""></div>
<div id="t"></div>
<div id="u"></div>
<div id="v"></div>
<div id="w"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="z"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="ba"></div>
<div id="ca"></div>
<div id="da"></div>
<div id="ea"></div>
<div id="fa"></div>
<div id="ga"></div>
<div id="ha"></div>
<div id="ia"></div>
<div id="ja"></div>
<div id="ka"></div>
<div id="la"></div>
<div id="ma"></div>
<div id="na"></div>
<div id="oa"></div>
<div id="pa"></div>
<div id="qa"></div>
<div id="ra"></div>
<div id="sa"></div>
<div id="ta"></div>
<div id="ua"></div>
<div id="va"></div>
<div id="wa"></div>
<div id="xa"></div>
<div id="ya"></div>
<div id="za"></div>
<script>

var color = ["orange", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "white", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green","navy","orange", "white", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "white", "red"];
var id = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","1", "ba", "ca", "da", "ea", "fa", "ga", "ha", "ia", "ja", "ka", "la", "ma", "oa", "pa", "qa", "ra", "sa", "ta", "ua", "va", "wa", "xa", "ya", "za"];
var ran3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);
 var ran4=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
function bbbl()
{

for(i=0;i<=51;i++)
{
 var ran=Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);
 var ran1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
document.getElementById(id[i]).style.backgroundColor=color[i];
document.getElementById(id[i]).style.left=ran+'px';
document.getElementById(id[i]).style.top=ran1+'px';
document.getElementById(id[i]).style.opacity="0.3";

}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create 52 `<div>` blocks inside my web page randomly. I am not getting desired output. The HTML DOM is not working. Only 20 `<div>` blocks are working.
Here I have used random function to set a different position to each individual `<div>`. The desired output should be 52 different colored blocks at different positions. But the result is different. Only blocks are in output.
Can I do this in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work..... I made the code really really simple....

**EDIT: Added Random motion..**

```js
var color = ["orange", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "white", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "navy", "orange", "white", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "white", "red"];

function getRandom(max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - 0) + 0;
}

function moveRandom(){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.left = (getRandom(window.innerWidth) -100) + 'px';
      box[i].style.top = (getRandom(window.innerHeight)  -100) + 'px';
    }
}

function bbbl() {

  for (i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div')
    el.classList.add('box')
    el.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
    el.style.opacity = "0.3";
    document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.childNodes[0])
    moveRandom()
  }
}

bbbl()
setInterval(moveRandom, 5000)
```

```html
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .box:hover {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.359127, -0.469472, 0.806613, 0, 0.190951, 0.882948, 0.428884, 0, -0.913545, 0, 0.406737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black" onload="bbbl()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, This was really amazing!! If possible can I make these boxes in a random motion???

Comment: Updated the code. please approve and upvote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Its working but there is an problem.If I add a new <div> element inside the body then design it with css its(css style) not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues. Firstly your HTML is missing the `#s` element. There are also only 50 elements in the array, so looping to `51` inclusive caused an out of bounds error. You could loop to `id.length` instead.

A better method altogether would be to select all the `div` elements (either by tag or class) and loop through them directly instead of having to maintain a separate list of all their `id` attributes. Try this:

```js
var color = ["orange", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "white", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "navy", "orange", "white", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "white", "red"];

function bbbl() {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('div');  
    els.forEach(function(el, i) {
      var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);
      var ran1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
      el.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
      el.style.left = ran + 'px';
      el.style.top = ran1 + 'px';
      el.style.opacity = "0.3";
    });
}

bbbl();
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease 0s;
}
div:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.359127, -0.469472, 0.806613, 0, 0.190951, 0.882948, 0.428884, 0, -0.913545, 0, 0.406737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
<div id="f"></div>
<div id="g"></div>
<div id="h"></div>
<div id="i"></div>
<div id="j"></div>
<div id="k"></div>
<div id="l"></div>
<div id="m"></div>
<div id="n"></div>
<div id="o"></div>
<div id="p"></div>
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="r"></div>
<div id="s"></div>
<div id="t"></div>
<div id="u"></div>
<div id="v"></div>
<div id="w"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="z"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="ba"></div>
<div id="ca"></div>
<div id="da"></div>
<div id="ea"></div>
<div id="fa"></div>
<div id="ga"></div>
<div id="ha"></div>
<div id="ia"></div>
<div id="ja"></div>
<div id="ka"></div>
<div id="la"></div>
<div id="ma"></div>
<div id="na"></div>
<div id="oa"></div>
<div id="pa"></div>
<div id="qa"></div>
<div id="ra"></div>
<div id="sa"></div>
<div id="ta"></div>
<div id="ua"></div>
<div id="va"></div>
<div id="wa"></div>
<div id="xa"></div>
<div id="ya"></div>
<div id="za"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks!! Actually I want an improvement in my code.If possible can I randomly make glow each of the block.I mean I want that each block to change its opacity from 0 to 1 for a random time period within 1s to 3s.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the DOM. You have issues in your code.

You have a div that has a blank id (s)

You have a div with an id that is a number (1). IDs can't be numbers.

You're array is missing (n) and (na).

```js
var color = ["orange", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "white", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green","navy","orange", "white", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "red", "green", "blue", "white", "red"];
var id = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","aa", "ba", "ca", "da", "ea", "fa", "ga", "ha", "ia", "ja", "ka", "la", "ma", "oa", "na", "pa", "qa", "ra", "sa", "ta", "ua", "va", "wa", "xa", "ya", "za"];
var ran3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);
var ran4=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
function bbbl()
{

for(i=0; i<=51; i++)
{
 var ran=Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);
 var ran1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
 var block = document.getElementById(id[i]);
block.style.backgroundColor=color[i];
block.style.left=ran+'px';
block.style.top=ran1+'px';
block.style.opacity="0.3";

}
}
```

```css
div
{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;

-webkit-transition: 1s ease 0s;

}
div:hover
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:100px;
-webkit-transform:matrix3d(0.359127, -0.469472, 0.806613, 0, 0.190951, 0.882948, 0.428884, 0, -0.913545, 0, 0.406737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<body  bgcolor="black" onload="bbbl()">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
<div id="f"></div>
<div id="g"></div>
<div id="h"></div>
<div id="i"></div>
<div id="j"></div>
<div id="k"></div>
<div id="l"></div>
<div id="m"></div>
<div id="n"></div>
<div id="o"></div>
<div id="p"></div>
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="r"></div>
<div id="s"></div>
<div id="t"></div>
<div id="u"></div>
<div id="v"></div>
<div id="w"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="z"></div>
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="ba"></div>
<div id="ca"></div>
<div id="da"></div>
<div id="ea"></div>
<div id="fa"></div>
<div id="ga"></div>
<div id="ha"></div>
<div id="ia"></div>
<div id="ja"></div>
<div id="ka"></div>
<div id="la"></div>
<div id="ma"></div>
<div id="na"></div>
<div id="oa"></div>
<div id="pa"></div>
<div id="qa"></div>
<div id="ra"></div>
<div id="sa"></div>
<div id="ta"></div>
<div id="ua"></div>
<div id="va"></div>
<div id="wa"></div>
<div id="xa"></div>
<div id="ya"></div>
<div id="za"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//--try using class instead of id block.

//example

.mydiv
{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;

-webkit-transition: 1s ease 0s;

}
.mydiv:hover
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:100px;
-webkit-transform:matrix3d(0.359127, -0.469472, 0.806613, 0, 0.190951, 0.882948, 0.428884, 0, -0.913545, 0, 0.406737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```